# how to animate google maps api circle?

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, css-animations

I have build a pulse animation in `CSS3`I would like to implement in to marker in google maps api unfortunately it is not possible direct insert in to the map. Is there any option to the `CSS3` animation **or**
Is it possible to make google map **circle** increase and decrease as an animation.

```
var myCity = new google.maps.Circle({
    center: bigOne,
    radius: 150,
    strokeColor: "#E16D65",
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: "#E16D65",
    fillOpacity: 0
});
var smallcircle = new google.maps.Circle({
    center: smallOne,
    radius: 300,
    strokeColor: "#E16D65",
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: "#E16D65",
    fillOpacity: 0
});
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/gbqzQ/4/

Answer (score 16):

You can change circle radius using `setRadius()` method and make animation using `setInterval()`:

```
    var direction = 1;
    var rMin = 150, rMax = 300;
    setInterval(function() {
        var radius = circle.getRadius();
        if ((radius > rMax) || (radius < rMin)) {
            direction *= -1;
        }
        circle.setRadius(radius + direction * 10);
    }, 50);
```

See [example at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/nuwem/1/edit).

**Update:** Radius on zoom: you have to change it with factor 2. See updated [example at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/nuwem/2/edit).

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. Does it possible to keep constant radius size ?

Comment: What do you mean? To have inner circle fixed and outer expanding/shrinking or something else?

Comment: the radius is big when zoom, I would like to keep in same size like this http://natgeo125.appspot.com/

Comment: Updated example. BTW: your animation with CSS doesn't work at Chrome. FF is OK.

Answer (score 3):

-- **2021 solution:** --

This may be an old question and answer but is still relevant for the Google Maps API nowadays **as of now (2021)**. Also using **svg** wasn't as popular back then. Therefore I used the inline style tag to create an animated svg icon that imitates a circle. You can set `width` and `height` to your desired requirements and add this as a marker with:

```
const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    icon: "/img/marker.svg"
});
```

SVG:

```html
<svg width="40px" height="40px" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
    <style>
        circle {
            fill: #d2546b;
            stroke: #d2546b;
            stroke-width: 1px;
            stroke-opacity: 1;
        }
        .pulse {
            fill: #7F40E2;
            fill-opacity: 0;
            transform-origin: 50% 50%;
            animation-duration: 2s;
            animation-name: pulse;
            animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        }
        @keyframes pulse {
            from {
                stroke-width: 5px;
                stroke-opacity: 1;
                transform: scale(0.3);
            }
            to {
                stroke-width: 0;
                stroke-opacity: 0;
                transform: scale(2);
            }
        }
    </style>
    </defs>
    <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="5px"></circle>
    <circle class="pulse" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="8px"></circle>
</svg>
```